# What is it to resolve a dependency?

Tags: dependencies, resolve

When I read this, I don't truly understand what it means - it makes sense in context but could someone explain what it is to 'resolve a dependency' please?

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, to "resolve a dependency" means to "go get" it (i.e. from the service container) so it can be "used" where it's being injected or "passed" into.

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned, it could mean different things in different contexts. In Java "resolving a dependency" usually refers to a library that you include (and use) in your project. When you're having "resolving issues" it's usually due to missing, incorrect or incompatible version of a library.